# How to use graphviz with neato style in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, graphviz, neato

I want to output the following code in the neato style.

```
from graphviz import Graph

dot = Graph()

dot.node('a')
dot.node('b')

dot.edge('a', 'b')

print(dot.source)
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dot.engine = 'neato'`for using the neato style.

Answer (score 0):

```
dot.graph_attr['layout'] = 'neato'
```